# make second button draw a line on the completed task

Tags: javascript

I am trying to draw a line throuh the task once the "done" button is pushed but i can't seem to put in the right code.

'''

```
function addTask() {
  let input = document.getElementById("task").value;
  if (input == "") {
    window.alert("You must enter a value in the New Task field.");
  } else {
    let taskList = document.getElementById("lista");
    taskList.innerHTML +=
      `<li ><span id=${input} >` +
      input +
      "</span ><button onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'           class='delete'>Delete</button> <button onclick='document.getElementByTagName('span').style.textDecoration = 'line-through''    class='done'>Done</button>";
   }
 }
```

'''

Comment: You need to listen to a click on the done button and then add a css class wich adds text-decoration: line-through; to the todo item
Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to have some code to test. What you have supplied is only one function and not what you've tried

Comment: There is no `document.getElementByTagName` function. There is an `getElements` but you get more than one with that. You can use `document.getElementById('${input})`  or something, not sure about the correct syntax because of writing this in comment without syntax highlighting

Comment: Please provide your full code to SOF community so that they can guide you better.

Answer (score 0):

<button onclick='document.getElementByTagName('span').style.textDecoration = 'line-through''

I am not entirely sure but it looks like you have an extra apostrophe sitting next to 'line-through'

What happens if you try to execute the code? Do you have some sort of fiddle available? Then i can investigate further.

Comment: I get : Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that when trying to target the task name, you're using a `document.getElementByTagName('span')`. So this is going to look at the whole document and find the first span while what you actually need is to search locally. The `querySelector()` method is easy to use since you can just use css selectors.

```
const input = document.getElementById('task');
function addTask(){
    const taskName = input.value;
    //check if task name isn't empty
    const newTask = `
    <li>
       <span>${taskName}</span>
       ...
       <button onclick = "this.parentNode.querySelector('span').style.textDecoration = 'line-through'">Done</button>
    </li>
    `;
    //append this to the task list
}
```

Comment: I actualy want to target the text in the li tag and style it to have a line go through it when I press Complete button